# g++ how to use make?

Tags: c++

I have this makefile

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall -Wpedantic -g
PROG = a
OBJS = other.o main.o
SRCS = other.cpp main.cpp

a: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.cpp

clean:
    $(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(PROG)

depend:
    makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRCS)
```

My other.cpp is

```
int f( ) noexcept // example function
{
    return 2;
}
```

My main.cpp is

```
int main( int, char** )
{
    f( );
    return 0;
}
```

So, obviously, When I run `make depend`, it only adds a line that says `#DO NOT DELETE`. However, upon compilation, when i run just `make`, i get this error for main.cpp: `‘f’ was not declared in this scope`. I think I'm missing something big here. Can anyone explain why this doesn't compile and what I should do?

Comment: I personally recommend employing header files. You will lilely need them later, or indeed rather sooner.

Comment: CC should not be a C++ compiler.  Use CXX for that.

Comment: And `CXXFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone :-). I'm not very familiar with makefile naming convensions, since i just started learning about makefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your Makefile.

The compiler's error message is self-explanatory. Functions must be declared before they are used, in C++.

Add a proper declaration:

```
int f() noexcept;
```

To your `main.cpp`.

Comment: Um, no, do not do this.